# why is the user authentication unsuccessful?

Tags: django, django-authentication

i am trying to build login page using django authentication system
below is the views

```
from django.contrib import auth
def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username','')
    password = request.POST.get('password','')
    print request.POST
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)  #returns user object if match else None
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)  #make user status as logged in now using django login function
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/todos')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>login page</h2>
<hr>
<form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username"><br>
    password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
 ...
 urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^', include('invoices.urls')),
     url(r'^todos/', include('todos.urls')),
     url(r'^accounts/login/$', todos.views.login, name='login'),
     url(r'^accounts/auth/$', todos.views.auth_view, name='auth_view'),
     url(r'^accounts/logout/$', todos.views.logout, name='logout'),
     url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$',todos.views.loggedin, name='loggedin'),
     url(r'^accounts/invalid/$', todos.views.invalid_login, name='invalid_login'),

]
```

[image]

The variable `user` returns `None` even if the user/password is correct.when i change this line `user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)` to actual user and password eg. `user = auth.authenticate(username="peter", password="P@$w0rD275")` it is successfully logged in

command line out put

```
>>>result=auth.authenticate(username='admin', password='adkd92')
>>>print result
None
>>>result=auth.authenticate(username='admin', password='admin123')
>>>print result
admin
```

Comment: do you have a form or it's just some post you're sending? I mean an AuthForm from django or whatever? Do username and password have value? Do they exist in db ?

Comment: yes the user/pass exist in django admin database.

Comment: when you get the request.POST.get('password', ''), what's the value ? is it a clear password or a hashed one?

Comment: the output of `print request.POST` is `<QueryDict: {u'username': [u'admin'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'M0rq44BC80fDOwJyMG3S1zLxaqiKPBWpDyPS8fAzSfsg8AKRfIHOA6xsHCxaZNbX'], u'password': [u'admin123']}>`

Comment: So your variables username and password are set to 'admin' and 'admin123' if you print them after the affectation? Did you try to do auth.authenticate in a django shell with this value hardcorded ```auth.authenticate('admin', 'admin123')``` and see what happen?

Comment: i have update the question with command output

Comment: print `username` and `password` after this line `print request.POST`

Comment: and all of a sudden its working automatically :/

Comment: I bet the issue was of the `commas` after the removal the local server probably didn't picked the changes and restarting a server or another change which causes the server to refresh might have fixed it.

Comment: correct, i re-added commas and that was the culprit, Thank you folks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have a simple typo, you have extra comma `,` at end of following lines:

```
username = request.POST.get('username',''),  # <---
password = request.POST.get('password',''),  # <---
```

Remove it and it should be fine I guess.

Comment: i removed the commas but it still returns `None` when i print the `user`

Comment: Are you using custom user model or the default one?

Comment: im using django admins default `"user"`

Comment: please show your updated `auth_view` after commas removal.